# Displaying checked items in CheckedComboBox in DevExpress using C#.net

Tags: devexpress

My current CheckedComboBox has a large list of items. I need to have selected list out of those items checked when the drop down is clicked. e.g CheckedComboBox will have P,Q,R and S as the itmes. But only P will have a tick in front of it.

Is there a property for this defined already?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question :(.  Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Well in the drop down menu in CheckedComboBoxEdit I need to have only certain items checked. not all the items. Was expecting a property like checkedComboBoxEdit1.SelectedItems = Items I need checked (or ticked)

Answer (score 0):

The CheckedComboBox control does not provide the CheckedItems (or SelectedItems) property .Use the editor's EditValue property to determine which Items are selected.